# How can I submit a form click a span element while I want to use ajax in form to prevent refreshing and also want to keep submit button for responsive

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

As from the title, I want to submit a form by click a span element. I also want to prevent the page from refreshing. I also want to add normal submit button for mobile view. But on submit won't work unless I directly submit the form. Is there a way to submit the form with ajax when I hit the span element? I also know that having submit elemnt in form might give trouble to sending data to php. So, is there a way to resolve this?
My code -

**HTML**

```html
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <form action="" class="w-50 m-lg-0 m-auto" id="contactForm">
                    <label for="name" class="change text-white minor- text-white change font mb-2">Your Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form text-white change bg-color" id="name" required><br>
                    <label for="email" class="change text-white minor-font text-white change mb-2">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form text-white change bg-color" id="email" required><br>
                    <label for="subject"class="change text-white minor-font text-white change mb-2">Subject</label>
                    <textarea class="form bg-color text-white change" name="subject" id="subject" required></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light title-font mt-5 w-75 m-auto m-lg-0 mt-lg-5 d-block" id="send" value="Send">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md 6 col-lg-4 d-xl-block d-none">
                <div class="parent">
                    <img src="photos/cloud.png" alt="cloud" class="cloud" width="700px">
                    <span class="change text-white fs-1 pos" id="paper">
                        <i class="fa-regular fa-paper-plane"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Jquery**

```js
    $("#paper").on("click", function () {
        $("#contactForm").validate();
        console.log("good")
        $("#contactForm").on("submit", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var dataString = $(this).serialize();
                console.log("nice")
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "_actions/sendmail.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function () {
                        console.log("best")
                        $("#paper").addClass("posRun");
                    }
                });   
            return false;    
        });
  });
```

Comment: Why aren't you using an actual button for this, why does it have to be a span? For accessibility reasons, you should really use a button. Format it to look like you want it to using CSS.

Comment: Does your "normal submit button for mobile" also use ajax to submit without page reload?

Comment: yep...i want to prevent refreshing in mobile too

Comment: @CBroe Not work when I changed to button too.

Comment: In that position, it would not currently be part of your form, so it can't submit your form either. Either put the form element around the whole row, or add a `form` attribute on the button.

Comment: @CBroe Yes...I put that before I test. But still not working

Comment: Probably because you are still adding the submit handler inside the click handler, instead of adding the submit handler to the form outside of that, without any "conditions" or dependency on any other events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never add additional events inside other event callback!

You should just trigger form submunition on click, not add event:

```js
$(document).on("click", "#paper", function () {
    $("#contactForm").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            console.log("good");
            form.submit();
        }
    });
});

$(document).on("submit", "#contactForm", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataString = $(this).serialize();
    console.log("nice")
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "_actions/sendmail.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function () {
            console.log("best")
            $("#paper").addClass("posRun");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: sadly, it didn't work. nothing happened when I click the span. I tried removing submit button from form but still not working

Comment: @ThantHtetAung Does it reaches _good_ output? Maybe form is invalid?

Comment: No...it didn't reach to *good* output. I also put the value correctly

Comment: Try calling `$('#contactForm').submit()` without validation first

Comment: Yeah it's work. Thanks you so much but that mean I can't validate my form?

Comment: When I send email from input button in mobile view, the email send me double times. That won't affect the user exp but is there a to resolve this?

Comment: @ThantHtetAung Ensure you don't double bind your event - comment out Ajax request and just see if that prevents all submits. If not - search where it can bypass your form hijacking

Comment: I commented about ajax request but still sending two messages. And I don't know about "Searching where it can bypass your form hijacking". What's that and how to resolve it, Sir?

Comment: @ThantHtetAung Well, I don't have your final code and can't help you with that